# Find similar words using AWS CloudSearch

Tags: php, amazon-cloudsearch

Is it possible to find similar words using AWS CloudSearch? By similar I mean... imagine I have a column with several distinct information like: full_name, first_name, age, last_name etc, and a search is make looking for f_name, as an example. It should return full_name and first_name. Is this possible?

If this is not possible, how would it be a possible way to make this with very fast response rate?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no support for this kind of search inside AWS CloudSearch